# Apostol's Calculus Vol 2, Chapter 10.20, Exercise 7

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, integrating-factor

Let $\mu(x,y)$ be an integrating factor of the differential equation $P(x,y)\,dx+Q(x,y)\,dy=0$. I already showed that we have $$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=Q\frac{\partial}{\partial x} 
\log|\mu| - P\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \log|\mu|.$$ Now I have to **deduce** that if $(\partial P/\partial y-\partial Q/\partial x)/Q$ is a function of $x$ alone, say $f(x)$, then the function $e^{\int f(x) \, dx}$ is an integrating factor of the equation.

I couldn't find the way to see this.

The previous exercise shows that the equation $y'+P(x)y=Q(x)$ has the integrating factor $e^{\int P(x)\,dx}$, but I don't know if I can use it here.

Comment: A hint:  just plug the formula for $\mu$ into the condition for exactness ($\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(P\mu)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(Q\mu)$) and do partial differentiation.  I do not know the book, but the previous exercise seems to have no relevance here.

Comment: Is your $\mu$ my $\mu$ or you are using it for $e^{\int f(x)\,dx}$? That condition is a necessary condition, but it is not sufficient to guarantee the exactness.

Comment: I will just suppose I am in a convex set. Thanks.